# Creating a hyperlink for LetsEncrypt to provide SSL Cert on Github Pages

Tags: ssl, github, github-pages, lets-encrypt

**Background:**
LetsEncrypt requires me to put a file (Type: none) with a specific filename and specific text in it in a path (hyperlink) so that it can find it.
The reason I need the SSL cert is because I have another domain(let's call it [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) which is what it redirects to when you type in [www.username.github.io](http://www.username.github.io))

**Path required:** [www.username.github.io/.well-known/acme-challenge/filename](http://www.username.github.io/.well-known/acme-challenge/filename) or 
[www.domainname.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/filename](http://www.domainname.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/filename)

**What I've tried:**
Creating the link by adding the required file into my Github repo (edit path using: backspace to remove a previous folder, / to create one).
This is not a jekyll site and in order to make the links work I read that I need to add an empty .nojekll file at the root, after which non-root links with folder names starting with "." began working.

**Problem:**
Every link except that specific link/path works.
Even [www.domainname.com/.well-known3/acme-challenge/filename](http://www.domainname.com/.well-known3/acme-challenge/filename) works!

However, the previous one that's the required link lands at "There isn't a Github Pages site here" or "File not Found".